# Upload data to redshift through node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Recently I am curious in whether upload data to redshift through node js is possible.
i followed the link below:
https://walkingtree.tech/loading-data-to-redshift-using-nodejs/
but i dont understand what it has been done via S3?
I would like to upload data to redshift through node js specifying the specific table and attribute field that i want to insert the data. Is it possible?

Comment: When you say attribute, do you mean column?

Comment: yes, like in a table there are id, name etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Redshift is a database. You can certainly connect to it **using a JDBC connection** and perform `INSERT` statements to add data.

However, adding individual rows is very inefficient in Redshift and stores data in a less-than-optimal format. When loading large amounts of data, it is best to load the data via Amazon S3. This allows Redshift to load the data in parallel across multiple nodes, and sort it for best database performance.

See: [Amazon Redshift best practices for loading data - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html)